# How to serialize an object of a class that have only a double pointer to a structure as it member variable

Tags: c++, pointers, serialization

[image]

I have a little knowledge of **C** trying to move to C++. In this course project, we are given some dll libraries to write a class in C++ that creates a data structure and perform some computations on it.

I have difficulties trying to write a function that serializes the object created from this class and a function to de-serialize and reconstruct the object.
I have gone through some tutorials online but I have not come across how to serialize the object and desterilize it when the member variable is a double pointer.

Below is part of the class and the main function. All the function parameters where specified by the lecturer

```
class DataStructure
{
    HEADER_A** head = nullptr;
    //fstream file;

private:
    int IdValidation(const char* pID);
public:
    
    //Constructor that creates empty data structure
    DataStructure();


    /*
        Constructor that reads data from a binary file. The file was created by function Write (see
        below). Fails if there occur problems with file handling
    */
    DataStructure(char* pFilename);

    //Copy constructor
    DataStructure(const DataStructure& Original);



    int GetItemsNumber(); //return the number of item in the data structure

    /*
        Serializes the data structure and writes into the specified file. Fails if there occur problems with
        file handling or if the data structure is empty.
    */
    void Write(char* pFilename);
```

Main function. I have implemented most of the other member functions, just the serialization and de-serialization that I can wrap my head around.

```
#include "DataStructure.h"

int main()
{
    
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    DataStructure* pds = new DataStructure;
    ITEM1* temp_item = (ITEM1*)GetItem(1, (char*)"A Ba");
    ITEM1* temp_item1 = (ITEM1*)GetItem(1, (char*)"A A");
    
    std::cout << pds->GetItemsNumber() << std::endl;
    *pds += temp_item;
    *pds += temp_item1;
    std::cout << pds->GetItemsNumber() << std::endl;

    


    delete pds;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is HEADER_A

```
// Declarations of HEADER_A, HEADER_B, HEADER_C, HEADER_D
// Declarations of ITEM1...ITEM10 are in Items.h
//
typedef struct headerA
{
    void *pItems;  // Pointer to the linked list of items. 
                   // Items may be of types ITEM1...ITEM10.
    char cBegin;   // The linked list contains objects in which
                   // the first letter of the second word
                   // of ID cBegin.
    struct headerA *pNext;
} HEADER_A;
```

Here is the content of the header file given to us

```
#pragma once
#ifdef ICS0017DATASOURCE_EXPORTS
#define LIBSPEC extern "C" _declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define LIBSPEC extern "C" _declspec(dllimport)
#endif
LIBSPEC HEADER_B *GetStruct1(int iItem, int nItems);
LIBSPEC HEADER_C *GetStruct2(int iItem, int nItems);
LIBSPEC HEADER_A **GetStruct3(int iItem, int nItems);
LIBSPEC HEADER_D *GetStruct4(int iItem, int nItems);
LIBSPEC HEADER_E *GetStruct5(int iItem, int nItems);
LIBSPEC void *GetItem(int iItem, char *pID = nullptr);
#ifdef INSTRUCTOR
LIBSPEC void SetInstructorMode(); // asks password
#endif
// iItem - index of item(s) to generate (1...10) and insert into data structure
// nItem - number of items to insert into data structure
// Functions CreateStructn() (n = 1...5) construct nItem items of type iItem and insert
// them into data structure. Their return value is the pointer allowing to access
// the data. In each item the member "code" as well as members presenting time or date
// are calculated by C++ pseudo-random data generators. The ID is randomly selected from
// list Colors.txt.
// Function GetItem() generates a stand-alone item of type iItem and returns the pointer
// to it. Its member member "code" as well as members presenting time or date are 
// set as presented above. If the second parameter of this function is zero pointer,
// the pID is selected from list Colors.txt. If not, the string presented by the second
// parameter is used.
// Examples:
// HEADER_B *ps1 = GetStruct1(3, 30);
// Creates data structure of type 1 consisting of 30 items of type 3
// HEADER_A **pps3 = GetStruct3(10, 100);
// Creates data structure of type 3 consisting of 100 items of type 10
// ITEM5 *pit5 = (ITEM5 *)GetItem(5, (char *)"A B");
// Constructs item of type 5, ID will set to "A B" (do not forget that "A B" is of type const string *)
// ITEM8 *pit8 = (ITEM8 *)GetItem(8);
// Constructs item of type 8, ID will set by program
// In case of failure all the listed here functions return zero pointer and in command prompt 
// window print the error message.
```

Comment: `DataStructure* pds = new DataStructure;` this is not java, no need for `new` unless you intend to manage its lifetime manually. Those `ITEM` casts are also not needed, `(char*)` is UB because it casts away `const`. How would you serialize this structure in C? What is even `HEADER_A`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Quimby, to the best of my knowlege, in C the members of the struct are serialized. But my difficulty here is I don't know what to copy during the serialization since I have an array of HEADER_A pointers as member variable. Also, I don't Know how to come up with a minimal example since some function depends on the dll the lecturer provided

Comment: Well, you don't have to copy the existing code, you can make a similar new code from scratch. In C the members are serialized, that's true but you do not want to do that with pointers in either language since you only get the address. Since I have no idea how the pointer structure looks like, I do not know how to help you. Is it a tree? Forest? Just a list of lists? Maybe you can flatten the structure?

Comment: @Quimby, I just added an image of the pointer structure. It is just a list of lists

Answer (score 1):

First you need a function to serialize the headerA struct.

```
void WriteHeader(std::ofstream &ofs, headerA *header)
{
    headerA *current = header;
    while (*current != nullptr)
    {
        ofs << // Here you write the contents of the list *pItems
        current = current->pNext;
    }
}
```

If I understand you correctly, the double pointer to headerA is a 2d array of headerA structs? In that case you probably need something like this:

```
void Write(char* pFilename)
{
    std::ofstream ofs (pFilename, std::ofstream::out);
    for (auto *row : this->head)
    {
        for (auto *element: row)
        {
            WriteHeader(ofs, element); 
        }   
    }
    ofs.close();
}
```

And then something of a reverse of this in your `DataStructure(char* pFilename);` method.

Comment: Hello @Akvit, I just update the question with the pointer structure of the datastructure. Since my pointer structure also contain ITEM1 struct, Would I need to have a WriteItem() method too as you illustrated for Header_A in your answer?

Comment: @WIF, you can write a different method, or write the serialization of your ITEM1 struct just in WriteHeader. I separated the WriteHeader as a different function just to make code more readable and easy to use. But you need to serialize the ITEM1, yes.